# What does this.async() do in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Kept on seeing this pattern in code, but couldn't find any reference to it in google or SO, strange. Can someone point me to reference for this.async() function?

```
  var done = this.async();
  // ...
  $.get(path, function(contents) { // or some other function with callback
    // ...
    done(JST[path] = tmpl);
  })
```

Comment: That's no built-in function. It must be provided by some library/framework.

Comment: This is a Grunt thing. this.async() is part of their Tasks:

https://gruntjs.com/inside-tasks#inside-all-tasks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is a way to work around the problem of `this` escaping inside callback. Without this extra reference the code would look like this:

```
$.get(path, function(contents) { // or some other function with callback
  //Wrong! `this` might no longer point to your object
  this.done(JST[path] = tmpl);
})
```

Unfortunately! `this` inside response callback is not the same as `this` outside of it. In fact it can be anything, depending on what `$.get` (calling the callback using) decides it to be. Most of the people use extra reference named `that` for the same purpose:

```
var that = this;
// ...
$.get(path, function(contents) { // or some other function with callback
  // ...
  that.async(JST[path] = tmpl);
})
```

This pattern also seems reasonable and readable.

Oh, and if you are curious about this syntax:

```
done(JST[path] = tmpl)
```

This is an assignment used as an expression. The value of assignment is the right-hand side, so this code is equivalent to:

```
JST[path] = tmpl;
done(tmpl);
```

Comment: -1: this doesn't answer the question about `this.async()` and instead talks about something that doesn't even occur in the question as asked. I'm baffled as to why @Tony accepted this answer.

Answer (score 20):

`var done = this.async()` and `done(blah)` is a clever trick to return a value fetched from asynchronous call (e.g. `$.get`) within a synchronous function.

Let's see an example:

```
var getText = function() {
  return "hello";
};
var text = getText();
```

It's a pretty straightforward function call so no puzzle here. However, what if you need to fetch the text asynchronously in getText() function?

```
var getText = function() {
  return $.get('<some-url>', function(text) {
    return text;
  });  // ??????
};
```

call to `getText()` doesn't return the text you want to get. It returns jquery's promise object.

So how do we make `getText()` return the text it gets from `$.get()` call?

```
var getText = function() {
  var done = this.async();
  $.get('<some-url>', function(text) {
    done(text);
  });
};
var text = getText();  // you get the expected text
```

Magic, right?

I don't know the inner-working of `this.async()` call yet. I don't know if there is a library provides that function, but you can see that Backbone.LayoutManager uses this trick https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/blob/master/backbone.layoutmanager.js (search for this.async).

Also, Tim Branyen (the author of backbone layoutmanager) briefly talks about it in his video tutorial (http://vimeo.com/32765088 around 14:00 - 15:00). In the video, Tim says Ben Alman came up with that trick. Take a look at this as well https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-sync-async-foreach

I think it's a pretty neat trick to mix async and sync functions.

Cheers,

Comment: I came across this in the Yeoman 'Creating a generator' tutorial (http://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html).

Answer (score 1):

`var done = this.async()` is a pattern used in Grunt to help perform asynchronous functions within a Task.

You need to invoke `done()` or `done(returnValues)` to tell Grunt the task is complete (after your chain of asynchronous tasks).

Read more about it:
https://gruntjs.com/inside-tasks#inside-all-tasks