# The role of this.async(); in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This might be a possible duplicate of this question [What does this.async() do in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072129/what-does-this-async-do-in-javascript) but that question is under a different circumstance and the **accepted answer got negative vote, hence wrong or original question unaddressed**. Also the most liked answer did not clarify it, the answerer also said so in his answer.

What is the actual use of `this.async();` is JS? Is it part of the core JS language or a conventional function used by libraries? I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you care about this over any other library, class, or whatever there is on the entire internet? No, it's not vanilla JS. The linked question has more info on where it might come from.

Comment: what `this.async()` is, depends on what `this` is - no such function `async` exists in core JS - as for documentation - the link you provided has a link to [some documentation](https://gruntjs.com/inside-tasks)

Comment: @ASDFGerte Not particularly. I was trying to use a library from npm and they required returning a promise or using 'this.async'. That particular library does what it's supposed to do pretty well than any other from the entire internet. Hence the confusion.

Comment: The [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072129/what-does-this-async-do-in-javascript#comment14492210_11072129) and the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13189539/1048572) on the question you linked should have all the information that you're asking for. Or how exactly are your circumstances different? At least please state where exactly *you* found such a `this.async()` code that we should tell you more about, otherwise I'm very inclined to close.

Comment: @Bergi, I found the first comment a bit too succinct . And the accepted answer has been negative-voted. The second answer is detailed but the linked posts don't explain how this.async(); is used by library developers. This explains it in a better way- https://github.com/sboudrias/run-async#readme. I found it after I posted the question by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The `this.async()` is not standard (core) JS function

```js
this.async();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else is wondering about this. I just found this link which kind of sums it up and details the use case. 
https://github.com/sboudrias/run-async#readme

And Grunt also use this same technique to know that an async task has finished.
https://gruntjs.com/inside-tasks